# How to convert 8- to 4-bit grayscale image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, grayscale

I had a color jpeg image and with the syntax below changed it to a grayscale png

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('../house.jpeg').convert('L')
img.save('house_gs.png')
```

But it is 8-bit, how can I make it 4-bit so that each pixel of it becomes 4-bit?

Thank you.

Comment: PD: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699263/save-grayscale-image-as-4-bit-png-with-python

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen that. I was hoping for a better approach, Is there any other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save grayscale image as 4 bit png with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699263/save-grayscale-image-as-4-bit-png-with-python)