# How to render a PDF to a 4-bit greyscale image using Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, grayscale, e-ink

I am building an e-ink-based auto-refreshing "newspaper" as wall decoration for my home. The e-ink panel I'm using supports 4-bit greyscale, i.e. 16 different levels of grey.

I am preparing the contents using LaTeX and would like to rasterize it to a 4-bit greyscale format using Ghostscript. Due to the relatively low DPI of the panel (~150ppi) I'd like to use anti-aliasing using the different grey levels.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find a suitable output device in the Ghostscript docs.

I have found:

- There's a 4-bit indexed color PNG output device, but I don't see how to set the palette
- There's `pnggray`, but it's 8-bit
- There's a 4-bit X11 output device, but running a headless X server just to screencap the output in the end seems super convoluted

Am I missing an option?

If I can't do this using Ghostscript, what would be the highest-quality way to turn the 8-bit greyscale PNG output into 4-bit greyscale?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this

Answer (score 0):

Having tried multiple combinations in GhostScript, I have to say when I did get anywhere near just gray the results were still 8 bit (see kens comment below) and thus less than desired, however some scriptable graphics apps use GhostScipt or other PDF handlers that then can batch convert a list using a settings file. [Similar questions and answers abound here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=4%20bits%20grayscale) There may be other ways such as using pngtopnm or [dividing bits by 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699263/save-grayscale-image-as-4-bit-png-with-python) but life is short.

Here are the results in my goto app IrfanView it will keep mono as mono and coloured text is high fidelity even at 4 bits.

[image]

**filelist.txt** for above (/filelist=txtfile     - use filenames from "txtfile" as input)

```
; UNICODE FILE - edit with care ;-)

C:\SandBox\apps\PDF\GS\10.00x32\bin\rgb.pdf
C:\SandBox\apps\PDF\GS\10.00x32\bin\SourceHelloWorld2.pdf
```

**Batch Ini file** severely trimmed just to show how settings are saved from GUI to be applied with above (/advancedbatch        - apply Advanced Batch Dialog options to image (from INI file))

```
; UNICODE FILE - edit with care ;-)

[Batch]
AdvCrop=0
AdvCropX=0
...
AdvUseBPP=1
AdvBPP=16
AdvUseFSDither=1
AdvDecrQuality=1
AdvAutoRGB=0
...
AdvGray=1
...
...
```

So consider a graphics app as more appropriate (Windows IrfanView does not need GhostScript but its a 2nd optional dependency)

Others are cross platform so will use GhostScript) **Gimp, ImageMagic or XnView** etc. are hot favourites for depending on Ghostscript.

Comment: With Ghostscript you would either need to create your own device or use a 4-bit screen to an 8-bit device, then strip the top nibble of each byte. There is no 'out of the box' solution for this (4-bit output is not a common requirement)